# Как заполнить массив класса , или массив на основе класса

Tags: java

Подскажите как это делается на примере класса человек. Нужно заполнить массив. Массив заполняется только по одному параметру или сразу по двум. Или же нужно два массива с именем и возрастом.Рандом в моем коде не работат.Обязательно ли нужен конструктор?

```
import java.util.Random;
```

public class Human {

```
int age;
char name;



public static void main(String[] args) {

Random ran=new Random();
Human[] humans=new Human[100];

for (int i=0;i<humans.length;i++){
    humans[i]=ran.nextInt(100);
}

}
```

}

Comment: что вы пытаетесь сделать здесь? Вас, как минимум, не смущает чтобы хотите присвоить элементам массива класса Human числовые значения?

Comment: я хочу заполнить массив возрастом, и именем. Хочу узнать как это делается . Нужно ли два массива?

Comment: нет не нужно два массива

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Human {

    private int age;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Human{" + "age=" + age + ", name=" + name + '}';
    }
    
    public Human(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random ran = new Random();
        Human[] humans = new Human[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < humans.length; i++) {
            humans[i] = new Human(ran.nextInt(100), "test_name");
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(humans));

    }

}
```

А если с использованием функционалки, то метод main можно написать еще проще:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Human[] humans = new Random().ints(0, 100)
            .limit(100)
            .mapToObj(age->new Human(age, "test_name"))
            .toArray(Human[]::new);
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(humans));

}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, задавайте свои вопросы, если вам что-либо не понятно

Comment: Еще проще нельзя сделать, по деревянному, если я только начал изучать класс и не знаю что такое оверрайд. и не стринг а чар. Получается что бы заполнить массив нужен конструктор в классе, без него нельзя?

Comment: @Mobsman аннотацию оверрайд вы можете убрать, она не обязательна. метод toString - это метод класса Object, достался вам по наследству (именно его мы переопределяем - оверрайд). это метод нужен для того, чтобы определить, как в консоли будут отображаться объекты вашего класса Human. чар может хранить только символ, поэтому все таки стринг, а не чар, если вы хотите хранить имя, а не один символ. конструктор не обязателен, но вам нужно как-то присвоить значение переменным  age, name, а через конструктор это сделать на много проще

Comment: рандом не работает на стринг?

Comment: @Mobsman  как вы себе это представляете? можете привести пример рандомной строки?

Comment: фцуафафпцййцуйцк

Comment: @если для вас не имеет значения содержание строки и это просто набор символов, то это решается иначе. класс Random генерирует исключиельно числовые значения. замените "test_name" на UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Comment: а если делать рандом чар, то ява может только один символ заносить в ячейку?

Comment: @Mobsman Java строготиризированный язык программирования. При объявлении переменной вы всегда должны указать тип этой переменной и в дальнейшем вы не можете его изменить. Базовые типы данных необходимо выучить и знать. char - является базовым типом данных, хранящим 1 символ. без вариантов

Comment: можно ли сгенерировать число и привести его к чару, у чара же каждая буква соответствует числу.

Comment: @Mobsman char по сути и есть int, например диапазон от 97 до 122 включительно соответствует маленьким латинским буквам

Comment: можно ли как то цифры привести к чару, , не нашел такого метода

Comment: @Mobsman метод не нужен, простой каст: char ch = (char) 28;

Comment: humans[i]= new Human(ran.nextInt(100),(char)ran.nextInt((90 - 25) + 25));  как правильно записать ( чар рандом+чар рандом+чар рандом) в параметр чар имени, можно ли так вообще писать

Comment: @ Mobsman так писать можно, только что вы ожидаете от записи 90-25+25, это же всегда 90 получится